# How to close dropdown Menu when the item is chosen?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In this dwopdown menu:

```
<div className="dropdown-content" onClick={this.handleDropClick}>
 <NavLink to="/Favorite" className="admin-item">Favorates</NavLink>
 <NavLink to="/AccountApproval" className="admin-item">Account Approval</NavLink>
 <NavLink to="/AddPlace" className="admin-item">Add fixed places</NavLink>
 <NavLink to="/AddNewAdmin" className="admin-item">Add new admin</NavLink>
 <NavLink to="/Favorite" className="admin-item">Favorates</NavLink>
 <NavLink onClick={this.logout} exact to="/" className="admin-item" >Log Out</NavLink>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it auto close when one of the NavLink's already chosen

Comment: how does the dropdown-content class show in the first place? is it through hover? What is inside the handleDropClick function

Comment: @UdenduAbasili Here is the full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-currying-oo33t?file=/src/components/navbar.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below for the change I made
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-cloud-qw7k4?file=/src/components/navbar.js

Basically I added a listener that that detects a change in route and unchecks your input checkbox which is responsible to show/hiding the dropdown. Since the navigation is not a Route Component i made it one with the withRoute component from react-router-dom package.

Unrelated to your question though, your map is showing over the navigation  dropdown so you should fix that

Comment: Great! Thank you. Do you know how to fix the map problem?

Comment: increase the z-index of the dropdown. i dont know how the map is rendered but make the z-index of the dropdown like 100